# How to search a GPS location in Android and have 2 different termination conditions?

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm trying to find a way to turn off the GPS immidietly in case a good enough location was found, while still having a time limit to "give up".

I tried to do this with the following strategy:

start checking for locations, as soon as a location that has an accuracy lower than the maximum tolerated, pass it to the next function for processing and stop looking for updates.

Also, to save battery life, if such location could not be found in 30 seconds, stop looking for location updates without passing a value (basically give up, and hope to better luck next time).

To count the 30 seconds, I'm using a handler. But as soon as I write the line `locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);` in the handler, the `locationListener` in the parenteses in both lines (the one in the handler and the one in the listener) turns red and reports an error: `The local variable locationListener may not have been initialized`

Here is my code:

```
private void checkProximity() {

    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //start tracking location
    final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        ...

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //if new accuracy is better than the best estimate - update the best estimate
            if(location.getAccuracy() < MAXIMUM_TOLERATED_ACCURACY) {
                //forward location to scanProximity and end the location search
                scanProximity(location);
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);  //FIRST LINE (see below)
            }

        }
    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            500, 0, locationListener);

    Handler h = new Handler();
    int delay = 30 * SECOND;        
    Runnable removeListener = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //if this code is reached - the maximum tolerated accuracy was not met in the period time 
            //extended to find a location
            //TODO stop the location manager and return without forwarding a value
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); //as soon as I write this line, the FIRST LINE and this line turns red.
        }
    };
    h.postDelayed(removeListener, delay);

}
```

Is there anyway I can do this differently so I won't get an error?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [Little Fluffy Location Library](http://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/downloads/detail?name=littlefluffylocationlibrary_r15.jar&can=2&q=) to work with GPS locations. Check out the examples codes and see which makes you more easy the solution to your problem , this is a beautiful way.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really what I'm looking for